# Embed google doc content in a web page

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

What's the simplest possible way to embed google doc content in a web page?

I want to use my google doc account as a simple cms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something more complicated than

File->Publish to the Web -> and then copy pasting the iframe snippet that gets generated?